# Apply EventListner on Multiple MovieClip Instances

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 10 movielclips on stage with name of "mc1,mc2,mc3....". I want to apply one eventlistner on all and I was trying to call using variable but its not working when I can directly with instance name it works.

can anyone help that how can i apply one function on multiple movieclcip instances

```
//var mc ="mc1";
var mc = this["mc" + 1];

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testFunction);

function testFunction(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Seconds elapsed: "+ e.target.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Movieclips are named `mc1`, `mc2` etc, you can just loop through them like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   this["mc" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testFunction);
}
```

Keep in mind that accessing Movieclips by their name like this can lead to problems at runtime if the names change. It will also not give you any errors when compiling because this is all checked and executed at runtime. So debugging this might be a pain.

Comment: Thanks its working but its giving this error also

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at Test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Test_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:12]
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at ADLAppEntry/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()

Comment: Thanks jens I have solved the problem I was missing an object on stage.

Comment: Minor fix here: should be `i <= 10`. Otherwise your code does not include the 10th element, `mc10`.